# Importing rdkit.Chem.Draw makes plt.show() freeze the program

Tags: python, matplotlib, import, freeze, rdkit

My issues can be summarized by the below minimum reproducible examples.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
plt.show()
```

Works fine and displays the graph, however

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from rdkit.Chem import Draw

plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
plt.show()
```

Causes the program to hang and not respond to any terminal input, in fact `ctrl+c` does not stop the program running. I tried importing `Draw` in the following way to try to make sure that there are no namespace collisions.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import rdkit.Chem.Draw

plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
plt.show()
```

This again causes the program to hang and not respond to any terminal input. I need to be able to import `Draw`, so is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: Works for me in Spyder as a .py-file and in console. `Matplotlib` `3.7.1` `3.7.2` and `RDKit` `2023.3.2` `2023.3.3`

Comment: The code which gives you problems works fine for  in Colab.